# One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination that's in use

Tags: android, firebase, release, sha1, android-app-signing

I am trying to ad SHA-1 Key from Google Developer Console to my Firebase project. I am getting error: "One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination that's already in use" Inside Project>Settings>Android App in my Firebase project.

I've tried:

- Removing project that already has same package name and SHA key.
- Checking if there is OAuth Credential on Google Cloud Console with same name and
  fingerprint.

After removing project on my firebase account with same fingerprint and package name I am still getting the warning on my firebase console.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: @AlexMamo Third day in.